# Как можно анимировать JPG картинку

Tags: javascript, html, css, jpeg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет! Мне поступил заказ на создание сайта. В целом нужно просто анимировать этот логотип. Знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше всего это сделать?
нужно что бы колёса логотипа крутились, а так же время от времени тележка как бы подскакивала на ямках, то есть чтобы изображение поднималось немного вверх, а после опускалось, причем сначала поднимаются колёса, а после сама телега. К тому же чтобы независимо от телеги приподнимались и опускались красные и жёлтые кружочки. А так же нужно чтоб зелёные завитки плавно появлялись и исчезали. Я додумался только до спрайтов, создать каждый кадр вручную, передвигая каждый объект, а после с помощью CSS это дело оживить. Но каждый кадр создавать долго. Есть идеи реализации проекта?

Comment: Для начала нарежьте картинку на составляющие и потом двигайте куда нужно, советую для длинных и сложных анимаций библиотеку [gsap](https://gsap.com/), можно объединить в один `timeline` все элементы и удобно манипулировать анимациями.